# Thymeleaf Spring Security - Store authentication into local variable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf Spring Security in my Spring Boot project.

In the html file, I have multiple times in a row a couple of checks to display text based on user role (Admin, user, not logged in).

```
<div class="container">
    <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')">Admin text 1</div>
    <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('USER')">User text 1</div>
    <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ANONYMOUS')">Not logged in text 1</div>
    ....
    <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ADMIN')">Admin text 2</div>
    <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('USER')">User text 2</div>
    <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('ANONYMOUS')">Not logged in text 2</div>
    ....
</div>
```

I know you can use a local variables with Thymeleaf. I would like to save the authority checks into local variables so I can write more efficient code afterwards. Example below, but the local variable part is obviously incorrect.

```
<div class="container" th:with="isAdmin=${hasAuthority('ADMIN')},isUser=${hasAuthority('USER')}">
    <div th:text="${isAdmin} ? "Admin text 1" : ${isUser} ? "User text 1" : "Not logged in text 1"></div>
    ....
    <div th:text="${isAdmin} ? "Admin text 2" : ${isUser} ? "User text 2" : "Not logged in text 2"></div>
    ....
</div>
```

Is there a way to store operations on user role or authority in a local variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated: You can use `${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(...)')}` to evaluate in Thymeleaf:

```xml
        <div class=container th:with="isUser = ${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''USER'')')}"...
          ...
```

Alternatively, you can access the authorities through an expression
(iterating over a Collection):

```xml
        <th:block th:each="authority : ${#authentication.authorities}">
          ...
        </th:block>
```

`${#authentication}` is an implementation of [`Authentication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.15.RELEASE/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html).

Updated example:

```xml
        <p th:text="${#authentication}"/>
        <th:block th:each="authority : ${#authentication.authorities}">
          <div th:text="${authority}"></div>
        </th:block>
```

Generates:

```html
        <p>org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@1a6c9e86: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@8892938c: Username: admin@example.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ADMINISTRATOR,USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffbcba8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: A031D4B4CAB26223C13AE9B30AA62212; Granted Authorities: ADMINISTRATOR, USER</p>

          <div>ADMINISTRATOR</div>

          <div>USER</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't print anything for logged nor unlogged user.
<th:block th:each="authority : ${#authentication.authorities}"/>
                <div th:text="${authority}"></div>
</th:block>

Comment: I had an "/>" instead of ">" at the end of the first line.  I've fixed my answer

Comment: So what is the best way to check in this case?

Comment: You can create a collcetion of strings from the authorities and use "contains".  I have also updated the answer with an alternative.